# Remove tweets with less than 3 retweets with Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

So far i have this code:

```
$('.js-stream-item:has(span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet:has(span.ProfileTweet-actionCount[data-tweet-stat-count="0"]))').toggle();
```

It works fine but only remove tweets with 0 retweets, how can i use the attribute "data-tweet-stat-count" by condition ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
$('div.stream-item-footer:has(span.action-retweet:has(span.actionCount))').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).find('span.actionCount').attr('data-tweet-stat-count')) >= 3;
}).toggle();
```

Comment: not working for me =/

Comment: @computerguy Check the answer of Brock Adams from my last question, use that code, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062362/how-to-convert-a-jquery-filter-for-use-with-waitforkeyelements/32062715#32062715