# How to convert a jQuery filter for use with waitForKeyElements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

This code removes tweets with less than 3 retweets, but now I have the refresh (AJAX) issue. How can I add [the `waitForKeyElements` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508) to fix it?

```
$('.js-stream-item:has(span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet)').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).find('span.ProfileTweet-actionCount').attr('data-tweet-stat-count')) < 3;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a static jQuery filter, like that, to an AJAX-aware `waitForKeyElements()` use is not too hard:

1. Your base selector just becomes the selector parameter.  EG:
   `waitForKeyElements (".js-stream-item:has(span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet)"...`
2. The `filter(function()` internals transfer to the waitForKeyElements callback almost as-is.  See the script, below.

Note that when using `parseInt()`, [you should always specify the base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7818903/331508) to avoid unexpected ("time bomb") behavior.

Here's a ***complete script*** showing the port, of that filter, to `waitForKeyElements`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove or hide nodes based on jQuery filter
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements (
    ".js-stream-item:has(span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet)", removeFilteredNode
);

function removeFilteredNode (jNode) {
    var twtCnt  = parseInt ( 
        jNode.find ('span.ProfileTweet-actionCount').attr ('data-tweet-stat-count')
        , 10
    ) 
    if (twtCnt < 3)
        jNode.remove ();
}
```

Comment: It works perfect, easier than I thought, you are very kind for helped me so quickly and detailed, thanks a lot!!!